# Carousel with rounded corners

Tags: android, kotlin, carousel

Is there the possibility of making rounded corners on carousel in Android Studio?

I used a background but it doesn't work

```
           <com.synnapps.carouselview.CarouselView
            android:background="@drawable/radius_fond"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
            android:id="@+id/carouselView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            app:fillColor="@color/neutre30"
            app:pageColor="@color/neutre"
            app:radius="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            app:slideInterval="4000"
            app:strokeColor="#FF777777"
            app:strokeWidth="1dp"/>




     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
       <solid  android:color="@color/fond">
       </solid>
      <corners android:radius="12dp"></corners>
    </shape>
```

I then used some code to make the corner radius.
It works but for a moment the square photo appears and then the corners become round

```
   var imageListener: ImageListener = object : ImageListener {
    override fun setImageForPosition(position: Int, imageView: ImageView) {
        // You can use Glide or Picasso here
        val transformation: Transformation = RoundedTransformationBuilder()
            .cornerRadiusDp(12f)
            .oval(false)
            .build()


        Picasso.get().load(sampleImages[position])
            .fit()
            .transform(transformation)
            .into(imageView)
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

do you have any other solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The CarouselView library has an implmentation for a viewListener as follows

[From the documentation](https://github.com/sayyam/carouselview)

```
public class SampleCarouselViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    CarouselView customCarouselView;
    int NUMBER_OF_PAGES = 5;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample_carousel_view);

        customCarouselView = (CarouselView) findViewById(R.id.customCarouselView);
        customCarouselView.setPageCount(NUMBER_OF_PAGES);
        // set ViewListener for custom view 
        customCarouselView.setViewListener(viewListener);
    }

    ViewListener viewListener = new ViewListener() {
    
        @Override
        public View setViewForPosition(int position) {
            View customView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.view_custom, null); // put the value of the XML of how you want your view to look like 
            //set view attributes here
            
            return customView;
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom layout as already mentioned in documentation.

or

For simple solution you can add `Cardview` as parent of `CarouselView`

```
        <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <com.synnapps.carouselview.CarouselView
                    android:id="@+id/carouselView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    app:fillColor="#FFFFFFFF"
                    app:pageColor="#00000000"
                    app:radius="6dp"
                    app:slideInterval="3000"
                    app:strokeColor="#FF777777"
                    app:strokeWidth="1dp"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

Comment: I have put in the app's build.gradle but it doesnt suggest to import CarouselView and the package. After hitting Build it says:`Could not find com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.5.` Do I do something wrong? Try yourself. Seems one got outdated.  (compileSdk 32   minSdk 21    targetSdk 32)